# Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2:site failed: Java returned: 137

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-site-plugin

I get an exception when project builds in Jenkins with `site` goal:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2:site (default-site) on project common: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2:site failed: Java returned: 137 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2:site (default-site) on project common: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2:site failed: Java returned: 137
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2:site failed: Java returned: 137
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.ExitStatusException: Java returned: 137
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute (Java.java:113)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask (AntBuilder.java:335)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted (AntBuilder.java:280)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod (BuilderSupport.java:160)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod (AntBuilder.java:215)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod (BuilderSupport.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call (PogoMetaClassSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call (AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.spotbugs.SpotBugsMojo.executeSpotbugs (SpotBugsMojo.groovy:1046)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke (PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.spotbugs.SpotBugsMojo.canGenerateReport (SpotBugsMojo.groovy:570)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.MavenReportExecution.canGenerateReport (MavenReportExecution.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.getReports (AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.render.SiteMojo.execute (SiteMojo.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :common
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I build a project from maven - `mvn clean compile site` it works and I get a site. But if I run the same process from Jenkins I get an error. But `clean compile` works fine. The only site doesn't work.

EDIT:

I added spotbugs config from parent's pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        //other plugins
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <timeout>9999999</timeout>
                    <maxHeap>3000</maxHeap>
                    <effort>Min</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <xmlOutput>false</xmlOutput>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${spotbugs.excludeFileBaseDir}/utility/spotbugs/spotbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace the issue is actually in the `org.codehaus.mojo.spotbugs.SpotBugsMojo` (which is triggered by the maven-site-plugin). There's not enough information here to help you further, but start checking the configuration of this plugin.

Comment: I added spotbugs configuration to the question

Comment: very weird they use the org.codehaus.mojo package, as it is not part of https://www.mojohaus.org/ ... I guess you should try to get an answer via https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs, this issue is too plugin specific. My guess would be something odd with your excludeFilterFile value, but that would be a total guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and decided to update the spotbugs version to the latest (4.6.0.0 as of today) in the pom. This fixed the error for me.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      <!-- Optional directory to put spotbugs xdoc xml report -->
      <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```